# Quitar palabras desde cierto punto de un string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero quitar palabras desde un punto de un string.

Tengo un *string* con el valor `demo1.dev.v4.google.com`.

Quiero quitar todo lo que vaya delante de `.dev` para que quede así
`.dev.v4.google.com`.

Lo he intentado con `replace()` pero necesito que sea dinámico.

```js
var uri = "demo1.dev.v4.google.com";
console.log("Antes:",uri)
uri = uri.replace("demo1","");
console.log("Después:",uri)
```

Necesito quitar lo que vaya delante de `.dev`, en este caso `demo1`.

Comment: Y ... ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: hacer un replace(), pero necesito que sea dinámico

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta: 1. explica mejor lo «dinámico» que dices, 2. agrega el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es extraer el *substring* que vaya desde `.dev` en adelante. Para ello se utiliza la función `substr`, que necesita la posición del primer caracter del *substring*.

Por ejemplo, si quieres extraer `mundo` del string `hola mundo` debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var string = "hola mundo";
var substring = string.substr(5);
```

Para hacerlo dinámico debes obtener la posición dinámicamente. Para ello se utiliza la función `indexOf`, que necesita la cadena que quieres que busque y retorna la primera posición de la primera ocurrencia.

Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener la posición de `mundo` en el string `hola mundo`:

```
var string = "hola mundo";
var posicion = string.indexOf("mundo");
```

`posicion` toma el valor *5*, que es la posición del primer carácter de la ocurrencia.

En tu caso específico, el código sería:

```js
var uri = "demo1.dev.v4.google.com";
console.log("uri original:",uri);

var posicion = uri.indexOf(".dev");
uri = uri.substr(posicion);

console.log("uri nueva:",uri);
```

Answer (score 4):

Se puede usar `split`, `slice` y `join`, y agregar el punto al principio `"." + uri...`:

Usando `split`: `uri.split(".")` convertimos `"demo1.dev.v4.google.com"` en un *array*:

```
[
      "demo1"
    , "dev"
    , "v4"
    , "google"
    , "com"
]
```

Usando `slice`: `split(".").slice(1)`, el parámetro *1* es para quitar *una (1)* palabra:

```
[
    , "dev"
    , "v4"
    , "google"
    , "com"
]
```

Unimos el *array* a un *string* mediante `join`: `slice(1).join(".")`, unimos con puntos (`"."`):

```
dev.v4.google.com
```

Por último se agrega el punto al principio: `"." + uri...`:

```
.dev.v4.google.com
```

Código:

```js
var uri = "demo1.dev.v4.google.com"
var nueva_uri = "." + uri.split(".").slice(1).join(".")
console.log(nueva_uri)
```

Answer (score 2):

Si queremos ubicar el primer punto en una cadena, se utiliza [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)

Para cortar una cadena en pedazos, podemos utilizar [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring)

Basandonos en estas dos funciones, simplemente buscamos el primer punto y cortamos desde ahi

```js
var uri = 'demo1.dev.v4.google.com';
var newuri = uri.substring(5);
console.log(newuri);
newuri = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("."));
console.log(newuri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres, se podría utilizar la función `.replace()` de *String* pero pasando diferentes parámetros:

```js
const regExp = /\w+(\.dev(\.\w+)+)/ ,
    funcion = ( string , despues ) => despues + '.'  ,
    resultado = "demo1.dev.v4.google.com".replace( regExp , funcion ) ;

console.log( resultado ) ;
```

Esto te devolverá todo lo que haya a partir de `.dev` (éste incluido).

Comment: Lo que pretende el autor de la pregunta es no poner el punto al final. Puedes [editar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/329101/edit) intentando obtener el resultado sin el punto al final.